# Create a User with aspnet schema and UserRepository/ EF ASPNET MVC 4

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq, repository, entity-framework-mapping

I have a question for creating a user in my bd.
I use a userRepository for creating a user in aspnet schema.

So for creating a user, i must create one row in aspnet_user and aspnet_membership table

the userId is an identity key so it's my bdd who manage this... So for now, i have this code in my UserRepository class :

```
    public aspnet_User CreateUser(string username, string password, string email)
    {
        using (WebsiteEntities db = new WebsiteEntities())
        {
            aspnet_User user = new aspnet_User();

            user.UserName = username;
            user.Email = email;

            db.aspnet_User.Add(user);
            db.SaveChanges();

            **User u = GetUser(username);**

            Aspnet_Membership member = new Aspnet_Membership();

            member.UserId = u.UserId;
            member.PasswordSalt = CreateSalt();
            member.Password = CreatePasswordHash(password, user.PasswordSalt);
            member.CreateDate = DateTime.Now;
            member.IsApproved = false;
            member.IsLockedOut = false;
            member.LastLockoutDate = DateTime.Now;
            member.LastLoginDate = DateTime.Now;

            db.aspnet_Membership.Add(member);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return u;
        }
    }
```

But, i don't think that it's a good way for creating a user with a foreign key between aspnet_User and aspnet_Membership ... Here, i have a username who is unique but if it wasn't i don't know how i will done ...

Someone can help me ? thank for your helps

Answer (score 0):

You should add the new member in through the Membership Framework.  After that is done get the UserId to use as the foreign key.

This is what I do, it may not be ideal but it works for me:

```
  var createStatus = MembershipService.CreateUser(model.UserName, model.Password, model.Email);

  if (createStatus == System.Web.Security.MembershipCreateStatus.Success)
  {
    var newUser = new User();

    newUser.DisplayName = model.DisplayName;
    newUser.Email = model.Email;
    newUser.UserUnits.Add(new UserUnit { UnitId = model.UnitId, Status = (int)UserUnitStatus.Request });

    using(var db = new Entities())
    {

    var temp = db.aspnet_Membership.Single(a => a.LoweredEmail == newUser.Email.ToLower());

    newUser.GUID = temp.UserId;

    db.Users.AddObject(newUser);

    try
    {
      db.SubmitChanges()
    }
    catch
    {
      MembershipService.DeleteUser(model.UserName);
      throw;
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Welcome");
  }
```